# jquery loop through table rows, get and store data in variables and output all the data as an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, html-table

I'm trying build jQuery function but I have not got very far.

I am trying to loop through each table row, get the data and compile each row of values into a unusable array. Then output the array into a textarea.

The idea is that so I can copy and paste the array into a new text box, and then a start a new challenge to make a jQuery function to intput that array data back into my html table.

Feel free to rename this question if you can think of better way to describe my question.

This is how far I've got...

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cqycyn6/7/

```
var data = null,
    $results = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results"] .acf-repeater TABLE TR.acf-row');

$("A#data_get").click(function () {

    $results.each(function () {

        var data = array(
            row = $('.order').html();
            report_results_position = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_position"]').find('INPUT[type="number"]').val();    
            report_results_rider = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_rider"]').find("SELECT OPTION:selected").text();
            report_results_L1 = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_L1"]').find('INPUT[type="text"]').val();
            report_results_L2 = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_L2"]').find('INPUT[type="text"]').val();
            report_results_L3 = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_L3"]').find('INPUT[type="text"]').val();
            report_results_T3 = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_T3"]').find('INPUT[type="text"]').val();
            report_results_time = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_results_time"]').find('INPUT[type="text"]').val();
            report_dnf_dsq = $('.acf-field[data-name="report_dnf_dsq"]')".find('input[type='checkbox']").val();
        );

    });

    $("TEXTAREA.clipboard").html(data);

});
```

I can't even get array to appear in the text box.

And from looking at my code i'm guess the array will just be the last row anyway. How do I store each row in my array in a usable keyed format.

Any jquery master help would be great thank you.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cqycyn6/7/

Comment: Numerous problems. New array syntax is invalid. You don't do anything with `var data` in the loop ... need to push it to another array. `var data` only has scope inside the loop.  Not isolating instances of class within the rows... `$(this).find(....` . Suggest you start with very simple table until you get the basics working. Make sure you are checking errors in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to clean up your markup, simplify your selectors and fix your syntax-errors. Check your console for the errors which are displayed there. This would make things a lot easier.

Additionaly you have to add `$(this)` in your `$.each()`-function to reference just the one and actual row, otherwise every the data from every gets stored.

```
row = $(this).find('.order').html();
```

To initiate an empty array write:

```
var data = [];
```

To store your data in an array, respectively an object you can try:

```
data.push(
        {
            'row' : row,
            'report_results_position' : report_results_position,
            'report_results_rider': report_results_rider,
            'report_results_L1' : report_results_L1,
            'report_results_L2' : report_results_L2,
            'report_results_L3' : report_results_L3,
            'report_results_T3': report_results_T3, 
            'report_results_time' : report_results_time,
            'report_dnf_dsq' : report_dnf_dsq
        }
    );
```

try a `console.log(data);` to check your data array.

To access your data use:

```
data[index].key
```

`index` = Index of the array (starting at 0)

`key` = name of the object-key within your data-array

E.g `data[0].report_results_rider` will output "Marc Marquez"

If you want to display your array in the textarea you can use:

```
html_data = JSON.stringify(data);
$("textarea.clipboard").html(html_data);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oss4neo6/2/)

**Reference**

[.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

[.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Empiric, thank you so much for this. Absolutely perfect. I can understand now its working in the fiddle, this has helped me alot. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: @joshmoto Can you tell me how will you send this to server through ajax and get those value in server side?